# AngurlarJS, Nothing happens on route change in IE on enter

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, routes

I have encountered a quirky problem in IE when using AngularJS (1.2.13).

The solution is in general a report-generator, which uses the routes to determine which report to show and the route parameters as the parameters for the given report.

One way to produce the exception is:

- I click on a link in the menu.
- Then I copy the url (from the address bar in IE).
- I click on another link in the menu.
- Then I paste the copied url into the address bar in IE and press enter.
  This works fine, the view changes to the correct view.
- Then I click on another link in the menu.
- And then I paste the copied url into the address bar in IE again and
  press enter.

After the final step, nothing happens, the view stays the same as it was. 
If I press F5 however, it changes.
If I click on another link from the menu the solution will change to that view. Pasting the url again into the address bar, will lead to the same behaviour, nothing happens. All subsequent pastes fails, only the first one works.

This happens only in Internet Explorer (IE10), not in Chrome or FireFox.

The urls are #-based.

Tried to attach an $locationChangeSuccess and $routeChangeStart event to check what happens, but neither event is called when I paste in the url the second time.

Is there anybody who has encountered this problem before or know what is causing the behavior?